# Fundamental question on stochastic independence

Tags: probability, independence

Let $X, Y, Z$ be random variables. If $(X,Y)$ is independent of $Z$, is then also $X$ independent of $Z$?

Comment: Yes. It may help to note that the event $\{ X \in A\}$ is the same as the event $\{X \in A, Y \in \mathbb{R} \}$, or in other words, $\sigma(X) \subseteq \sigma(X,Y)$.

Comment: Thanks, if I may ask an additional question on this way: Let $\tau$ be a integer-valued r.v., is then $X_\tau$ independent of $Z$, the same as saying $(X, \tau)$ independent of $Z$?

Comment: $X_n$ is some stochastic process? No, this is not the same. For instance, it could be that $X_n$ is constantly zero, so $X_{\tau} = 0$, while $\tau = Z$.

Comment: Yes, a stochastic process. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intuitively, if $(X,Y)$ is independent of $Z$, then $Z$ provides no information about both $X$ and $Y$, so $X$ and $Z$ are independent.

Formally (for discrete case):
$$p_{X,Y,Z}(x,y,z)=p_{X,Y}(x,y)p_Z(z)$$
\begin{align}
p_{X,Z}(x,z)=&\sum_y p_{X,Y,Z}(x,y,z)\\
=&\sum_y p_{X,Y}(x,y)p_Z(z)\\
=&p_{X}(x)p_Z(z)
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

I thinks the answer is yes.

method 1)

$$P(X\in A , Z\in B)=P(X\in A, Y\in (-\infty, \infty), Z\in B)$$
$$=P(X\in A, Y\in (-\infty, \infty) )P(Z\in B)$$
$$=P(X\in A )P(Z\in B)$$

Method2)
 since

$$\sigma(X) \subset  \sigma(X,Y)$$ so

when $Z$ is independent of $(X,Y)$ then 
any events in $\sigma(Z)$ are independent of $\sigma(X,Y)$. [IndependentStochasticProcesses](https://planetmath.org/IndependentStochasticProcesses)

In hence 
any events in $\sigma(Z)$ are independent of
$\sigma(X)\subset  \sigma(X,Y)$.

So $Z$ and $X$ are independent.

On the other hand if $Z$ is independent of $(X,Y)$ so for any 
$A\in \sigma(Z)$ and $B\in \sigma(X,Y)$
$$P(Z\in A ,(X,Y)\in B)= P(Z\in A ) P((X,Y)\in B) $$ .

so if $D\in \sigma(X)$

$$P(Z\in A ,X\in D)= P(Z\in A ) P(X\in D) $$
since $D\in \sigma(X)\subset \sigma(X,Y)$